# Python utf-8 prints /xe2 /x9d from twitter names with tweepy, How can I fix this?

Tags: python, twitter, utf-8, tweepy, codepages

This is the script

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler()
auth.set_access_token()

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, count = 200).items():
    print(friend.name.encode('utf-8')
```

All I'm trying to do is print twitter followers names using tweepy, it prints most out but with some I receive "/xe4 /x9d"
I've tried using different code pages but none seem to work. I'm also using Pydev for Eclipse as an IDE, I left the auth and auth.set blank on purpose, please let me know if this is fixable to display the proper name of the twitter follower

Comment: `print()` takes strings in Python 3; don’t encode its argument to bytes. `print(friend.name)`

Comment: Thanks @Ryan but then i receive this error                                            return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2757' in position 14: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: If you run your script with `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python …` (and no `encode`), does it produce garbled output?